Why not BOTH Debug.Assert and Exception Throwing
This Debug.Assert vs Exception Throwing has been beaten to death. I understand the difference. Assert is a programmer error; an exception is for an external unexpected condition. I get it.
But, in the code I write, I sometimes use AgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(theParam) and sometimes Debug.Assert(theParam != null). And I bet half of you does the first and the other half - the second :)
So - why not use both? Maybe
TestStringArg(string theStringArg)
{
    Debug.Asert(theStringArg != null);
    Debug.Assert(theString != string.Empty);
    ArgmentNullException.ThrowIfNull(theStringArg);
    ArgumentException.ThrowIfNullOrWhiteSpace(theStringArg);
}


If they have the exact same condition, then only one can get triggered before throwing. What's the point of adding something if it will never impact the final result? It's like writing if (x is null) x ??= null; or if (false) { throw Exception(); }

What do you gain by doing both? It's like you would write a condition as if (x == 4 && isFour(x))

Where I work at the moment we came to the agreement that we use exception throwing on the "edges" to assert start conditions. In the "core" some of us use debug.assert, never exceptions for the one reason that the assertions will be "optimized away" in release mode.

@ipodtouch0218  and knittl The Debug.Assert are edited out during production, and only the exceptions are left. So your question is: Why add the Debug Assertions if we already have the exceptions? IMHO: Because they halt the program at the earliest possible moment.

"Debug.Assert are edited out during production" then just only use exceptions if you always want the error checking.

https://blog.michael.gr/2020/05/on-validation-vs-error-checking.html

“I understand the difference.” Sorry, from your words, it looks like you don't understand these two things. Or maybe you understand something but cannot formulate properly. To start with, neither Assert nor exceptions are errors.

Sorry, no, your explanation of Debug.Assert.System.Diagnostics and exceptions are incorrect.
It looks like you think you are using Assert as a different form of throwing exception on some runtime condition passed as a first Assert argument. And this is not true. This is because Assert throws an exception on two conditions: one of them is the runtime condition, that first argument, and the second condition is compile-time, that is, it depends on a compiler option. Some build configurations use the flag forcing the compiler to use assertions (most typically, such configurations are named DEBUG) and others — to ignore assertions completely, then no code related to assertion gets into the compiled code.
For the practical purposes, this mechanism is the most important. This way, you can use assertions only during development, and they are very useful. For the production builds, however, the assertion mechanism is completely removed from code. In the fully developed, well-debugged and tested code, you don't need to waste any CPU time for the redundant checks of the conditions used by assertions. It makes the assertion mechanism very useful for development.
So, should you also throw exceptions based on runtime conditions, ever? In some cases, you can, but not many cases, in contrast to assertions that could be used quite extensively, it depends on the development style.
With explicitly thrown exceptions, you need to understand that they are thrown regardless of the build configurations and any setting, so you need to be careful and think twice. In very many cases, it won't be a good practice.
